# Why am I getting a "Error: invalid address" in Solidity/Remix?

Tags: solidity, remix

When I call the "setStartTime" function, it works but when I check "_startingTime" I get this error:

call to timeTracker._startingTime errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid address (argument="address", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=address/5.1.0) (argument=null, value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.1.2)

Why am I getting this? If I am able to set time, then the mapping should have something to return?

```
contract timeTracker {

    mapping(address => uint256) public _startingTime;
    uint256 constant ONE_DAY = 86400;

    function setStartTime() public returns (uint time) {

        _startingTime[msg.sender] = block.timestamp;
        return _startingTime[msg.sender];
    }

    //checks if 24 hours have passed
    function checkIfDayPassed() public {
         //86400 seconds in a day
        require(block.timestamp - _startingTime[msg.sender] >= ONE_DAY, "Claim not ready");
  _startingTime[msg.sender] = block.timestamp;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code above, `_startingTime` is defined as a mapping. When calling it, you need to pass it a correctly formatted address as an input for it to return anything meaningful. Apparently, you were calling it without passing in any value.

Comment: ah yeah, I see where I went wrong. I had thought that remix might have passed an address for me, but I had to enter it manually. Cheers!

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with the same error. What kind of address do I need to be passing? Thanks.

Comment: Just any valid Ethereum address. You could learn more about what makes an address valid here: https://info.etherscan.com/what-is-an-ethereum-address/